# Trying to setup Neo4j 3.2.0 in ubuntu server

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to setup Neo4j version 3.2.0 in the ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS

Downloaded the tar and extracted the folder, edited the config file to update the port to 4444, for the time being disabled the bolt connector, listen_address to 0.0.0.0 for the http connector, authentication also disabled just to get started.
bolt connector is updated with the port 7687 even though it is disabled as i was trying earlier with it enabled.

Now when i try to connect to the `http://serverip:4444/browser`, it says Database access not available and shows me the login screen with host prefilled `bolt://serverip:7687`

Also I see this error on the console window
WebSocket connection to `ws://serverip:7687/`

> failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Dont understand the issues here, please help me out. I am not sure why is it trying to do a WS to the port assigned to the bolt, when it is disabled at the first place.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of juggling going on for HTTP connector support between the browser and the driver being used, a handoff which isn't complete, and the state of things is the browser is only supporting bolt connections right now.

The javascript bolt driver is being upgraded to handle http connections, I think, so you may need to wait until the next 3.2.x release to use the http connector again.

I think [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/511) should be tracking it.